# How to get number of video views with YouTube API into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, youtube, google-sheets

Anyone figured out a way to get number of video views with YouTube API into Google Docs?

Up until recently I was successfully using the method outlined in the [YouTube View Count in Google Spreadsheet](http://www.davidtoy.co.uk/post/26846394704/youtube-view-count-in-google-spreadsheet) blog post by David Toy.

But it stopped working recently and I began to get the below error:

> ```
> Request failed for https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Prv2-9U39K8?v=2&alt=json returned code 410.
> Truncated server response: <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
> <error><domain>GData</domain><code>NoLongerAvailableException</code>
> <internalReason>No longer avai... 
> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 2, file "Code")
> ```

Has anyone run into this? If so any ideas on how to fix it would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably due to Youtube (surprise surprise) yet again changing a portion of their API. You'll have to take a look at their API documentation to see if this has changed, most likely.

Comment: You need to migrate to v3 of the API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).  There are many posts about this on the [tag:youtube-api] tag.

Answer (score 4):

The script from that blog post uses v2 of the API which has now been deprecated and switched off. The new version would be:

```
function getYoutubeViews(videoId){
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=" + videoId;
  url = url + "&key={YOUR-API-KEY}";
  var videoListResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = JSON.parse(videoListResponse.getContentText());
  return json["items"][0]["statistics"]["viewCount"];
}
```

In order to make this work you will need an API key. [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) is the guide on the YouTube developers site which explains how to get the key. Once you have obtained your key simply replace `{YOUR-API-KEY}` in the code above with it.

To call the function from a Google spreadsheet, select a cell and enter: `=getYoutubeViews("{YOUR-VIDEO-ID}")`. For instance, `=getYoutubeViews("IiPJsI8pl8Q")`.

Comment: `Utilities.jsonParse()` is also deprecated... use `JSON.parse()` instead.

Comment: Please were did you get the UrlFetchApp variable from?

Comment: The URLFetchApp class is part of the Google Apps services: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app