# How to get video viewcount?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, youtube-api

I have a `video id` what I would like to know is.  Can I use Google App script to get view count of a YouTube video?

It is possible for the whole channel with `YouTubeANalytics.Reports.query`, but as far as I can see the query only supports channel id or owner id for id, not individual ID's.

There was a function viewcount that seems to have gone. Is there some other way that replaced it? The code below gets views for the channel.

```
 var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(
    'channel==' + channelId,
    oneMonthAgoFormatted,
    todayFormatted,
    'views,likes,dislikes,shares',
```

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898351/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api-into-a-google-spreadsheet/30909609#30909609